# How to implement remember me login functionality using Java-EE-7/JAX-RS-2.0(Jersey)

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I know how to implement Authentication & Authorization  using `Rest API`.
Here is the [link](http://www.developerscrappad.com/1814/java/java-ee/rest-jax-rs/java-ee-7-jax-rs-2-0-simple-rest-api-authentication-authorization-with-custom-http-header/)

I'm searching for remember me login functionality using ,`Java-EE-7/JAX-RS-2.0(Jersey)`  but i couldnot find the related example in web.

Can any one provide some ideas or any link of tutorial for implementing remember me login functionality using `Java-EE-7/JAX-RS-2.0(Jersey)`

Comment: Not sure about jax but it is something to with browser cookies

Comment: Only custom solution. Java-EE-7/JAX-RS-2.0 will not help you with that